# GNU Screen Problems

Tags: bash, process, jobs, pid, gnu-screen

I am trying to run `screen` in a special way (I am making an unusual script), and it is not working correctly.

---

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#startserver


set -m

cd /home/USER/SERVER_FOLDER/

screen -Dm -S SERVER java -Xmx768M -Xms768M -jar ./JARFILE.jar $@ &

PID=$!
echo $PID > ./.mc.pid
(sleep 0.5; sudo /usr/bin/oom-priority $PID) &

(wait $PID; startserver_after) &

screen -r $PID.SERVER
```

`/usr/bin/oom-priority` is a coommand I made that sets the priority of the pid to `-16`.

`startserver_after` is a command I want to run after `java` exits.

This isn't working because I cannot resume the `screen`. Looking at the `screen` manpage:

```
-D -m   This also starts screen in "detached" mode, but doesn't fork a new process. The command exits if the session terminates.
```

That should mean:

1. The `pid` of `screen` should be the same as that of `java`, however that works.
2. It is still `screen`, so I should be able to get to it by `screen -r SERVER` (but I can't).

When I run the line without the ampersand putting it in the background, it just does nothing until `java` exits. There is no output.

Comment: you're not literally using code `screen -r SERVER` are you? That is not documented use. from `man screen` : ` screen -r [[pid.]tty[.host]]` OR `screen -r sessionowner/[[pid.]tty[.host]]` . Good luck!

Comment: @shellter aside from $PID, names in all caps are replaced with info that may be confusing/misleading or confidential. But thanks for the info from the manpage. I updated the script.

Comment: what dose `screen -r SERVER` return?

Comment: It' a problem with sessions, you don't have one. eg. login session. Put a `echo $(ps -auxw | grep $PID)` just after the `echo $PID > ./.mc.pid`. The screen isn't there because there is no session to attach to/from. A script is not a session.

Comment: Also why is there a valid $PID after wait? wait "waits" until the child process **completes** during a fork. So once wait returns there is no PID to return to, because the process has finished. Google "fork and recall processes in bash".

Comment: @shellter - If you name a screen session with `screen -S SomeName`, you can indeed use `screen -r SomeName` or `screen -x SomeName` to reattach to it, regardless of PID/tty; you only need again to specify the PID/tty if you have multiple screens with the same name.  See GNU Screen Manual section on the `-S` argument.

Comment: What `screen -ls` returns ?

Comment: The PID of the screen can not be the same as the PID of the java process. No two processes can have the same PID at the same time.

Comment: @MichaelTomkins in `(wait $PID; startserver_after) &`, the ampersand puts the two commands in the background. A process is forked that runs those two commands one after another detached from bash. In the meantime, `screen -r $PID.SERVER` is run.

Comment: @Coder256 What are you actually trying to achieve? Maybe there's another way to achieve your goal that is way simpler...

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve , maybe tmux can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you run screen with `-Dm`, it will not return to you command line prompt (the "no fork" idea; that's why it doesn't do anything until your java exits if you have no ampersand). If you run it with the `-dm`, it returns to your command line prompt immediately.

By putting the `-Dm` in the background, you have caused it to fork and set `$!` with the PID of your screen process. So that's good.

You are setting the `oom-priority` of your screen (I doubt you want to do that; I think you were aiming at Java). You can get the pid of your child, like this:

```
pidchild=$(pgrep -P $PID)
```

Do you really want to `startserver_after` after the screen exits? Maybe you want to `wait` on the child, as well.

Regarding the `screen -r` at the end: It should work, unless you don't have a tty as stdin of your script, or the java has already exited. Try a `ps -p $pidchild` immediately after the `screen -r` and see if the child is still alive. Also run `tty` as the last command of your script, and make sure it does not return `Not a tty`.